# How to use the git in the Rails Project with Web Designer

Tags: git

I have a Rails project that use the git to check the history. My web designer co-worker helps me to do the html and css and using the git to check her project too. Thus there are two git repos need me to check. Sometimes I want to change some small css things by myself. But I find it is very bad, because I need to commit the same stuff to git at two repos .

How can I work with my web designer co-worker?

The folder directory as the following:

#### Rails:

```
blog/    
  -app/
    -assets/
       -images/
       -javascripts/
       -stylesheets/
    -controllers/
    -..../    
  -config/    
  -...../
```

#### Html:

```
blog/
   -assets/
      -images/
      -javascripts/
      -stylesheets/
   index.html
   about.html
```

If I use the submodule that add the html project to the Rails project, need I to change the Html project's directory structure and how can I ignore the `index.html` and `about.html` in the Rails project?

Comment: Why do you need two repos for one project ?

Comment: There are a lot of unless files which are in the Rails project for Web Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `submodule`:

```
$ git submodule add path/to/remote/ui/repo path/to/local/ui/folder
```

When you need to modify part of your UI files, just cd into `path/to/local/ui/folder` and do it. Just treat it as a seperate repo.